# Showing Discount offer on the cart

Tags: shopping-cart, discount

When user add products, it will be added to the backet cart. On the Basket list, you can see there is a 50% discount offer for Chicken Fillet Burger. Normal price is $5.00 and discounted for $2.50.

There might be other item that has special offer such as `Buy 2 for $2.50` (only same product). How can I present this on the basket **without** grouping two product together? You can see there is two items of `Grilled Panini` and the discounted for $2.50 (Buy 2 for $2.50). The total of "Grilled Panini" items is $2.50, not $5.00

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't group multi-buy discounted items together?

(Also, the 2 Chicken Filet Burger line may need looking at to clarify the price per item vs multiple item subtotal)

Comment: @AndrewMartin because each item may have different extras like chilli sauces that can be added on top for extra charge. (An item can have many extras added on top)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is this, as discounts change, you can, of course, move the individual promotion lines below each grouped item, however in that case you would need to update the sub-total correctly.

[image: Bill]

Answer (score 0):

This would be my choice. In this case, the second one is actually free, so that's what I'd put.  If it were cents off, I'd say "check box to get second one for $0.50 (or 50¢, or whatever is most readable)

[image]